# How to redirect user to requested resource after login succeeded

Tags: .net-core, forms-authentication, credentials

Hello i am supposed to port a `.NET Framework` project to `ASP NET Core`.

The user requests a url , he is getting redirected to a `login` session and i want after that , if `credentials` are ok , to redirect him back to the requested resource.
The project is written in `.NET Framework` and uses `FormsAuthentification` class , more specifically the method `RedirectFromLoginPage`.
What would be an equivalent to the above-mentioned method in `.NET Core`.

Comment: Are there any `docs` to i can look into ?